# output data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, data-visualization

I am trying to relate tables together so that a patient's illness and priority have a specific waiting time associated to it. Here are the tables;

The illness tables holds info about the patient illness (critical, immediate, urgent, semi-urgent, non-urgent)

Priority table hold info about the patients priority (high, moderate, low).

I want it to link so that a specific priority and illness has a specific time: for example:

```
Patient   Priority  Illness     Arrival_Time 
1         Low       non-urgent  12.00am
2         Low       non-urgent  1.000pm
```

I need some simple PHP to recognize that based on the priority "low" and illness "non-urgent" the expected waiting time is 2-3 hours to display these results.

```
Patient   Priority   Illness      Arrival_Time   Expected_Waiting_Time
1            Low        non-urgent   12:00am        (Arrivaltime + waiting time(3 hours)
```

Comment: Please show your table schema. Are you storing time as a varchar or `TIME` field

Answer (score 0):

Im suggesting you to create table with information about additional waiting times:

Table Priority:

```
id
name
waiting_time
```

Same with table Illiness:

```
id
name
waiting_time
```

And then your table should look like:

```
Patient   Priority  Illness     Arrival_Time 
1         1         1           12.00am
2         1         1           1.000pm
```

Next step is query:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    prt.waiting_time AS priority_waiting_time,
    prt.name AS priority_name,
    ill.waiting_time AS illness_waiting_time,
    ill.name AS illness_waiting_time,
FROM
    patient p
JOIN 
    priority prt ON (prt.id=p.priority)
JOIN
    illness ill ON (ill.id=p.illness)
```

And now, when you get this record from database you can easly calculate what expected waiting time as:

```
expected_waiting_time = arrival_time + priority_waiting_time + illness_waiting_time
```

Comment: thanks for your response Kasyx I have added the additional tables. I am looking for simple code to generate waiting times for certain conditions. So, IF a patients priority is low and their illness is non-urgent THEN they have a waiting time of 2-3 hours